# How to get jQuery mobile listview working with checkbox AND icon

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, jquery-mobile

I try to get a layout like in the image attached in my jQuery mobile listview. I am currently using the class .ui-li-icon on the star image, but I don't get it alogn to the right, even if I overwrite the positioning by an own css attribute.

I could of course force the star to be on the right by position:absolute; but this would cause problems on different plattforms and between landscape vs portrait mode.

What is the best way to get a layout like below in jQuery mobile?

image: http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/095/Purple/ff/1d/33/mzl.ecpvufek.320x480-75.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into these links:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/lists-formatting.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/lists-icons.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html

Explore the List View Documentation:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I now use split button lists, but I can not figure out how to use my own imagery for the split button. do I have to overwrite the css or is there any other (better) way?

Comment: @Pat I suggest posting another question with some example code you have tried and what's exactly not working. http://jsfiddle.net helps as well

Answer (score 2):

i rethought my old answer and re did the issue especially to fit the mvc 4 framework but the client side is all the same.
so lets start:
if you just want the html you can get it here
this link is to a 3 parts checkbox list, the checkbox, the link to the item and the info popup:

[Here is the link to jsfiddle for working listview with checkbox AND icon](http://jsfiddle.net/yakirmanor/PBQ3P/)

iv added at the end some 2 parts listbox and a single part, for any questions let me know.

now for the controller all you need to do is

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Items(string act, 
    string tab, string search_by, string search, string sort, string sortdir, int? page, int? resultsPerPage,
    List<int> selected, int? projectId, string username)
{
    if (act == "AddItemsToUser")
    {
        string response;
        if (selected != null)
        {
            response = "Project Items Added:";
            foreach (var item in selected)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (username != null)
                        if (UserItemRecordModel.InsertUserItem(username, item, null, null, 0, null, null))
                            response += item + " - inserted, ";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    response += item + " - " + ex.Message + ", ";
                }
            }
            response.TrimEnd(' ', ',');
        }
        else
        {
            response = "No Items Were Selected!";
        }
        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else if (act == "AddItemsToProject")
    {
        string response;
        if (selected != null)
        {
            response = "Project Items Added:";
            foreach (var item in selected)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (projectId != null)
                        if (ProjectItemRecordModel.InsertProjectItem(projectId.ToString(), item, null, null, 0, null, null))
                            response += item + " - inserted, ";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    response += item + " - " + ex.Message + ", ";
                }
            }
            response.TrimEnd(' ', ',');
        }
        else
        {
            response = "No Items Were Selected!";
        }
        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else if (act == "RemoveItemsFromUser")
    {
        string response;
        if (selected != null)
        {
            response = "Project Items Removed:";
            foreach (var item in selected)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (UserItemRecordModel.DeleteUserItem(username, item))
                        response += item + " - deleted, ";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    response += item + " - " + ex.Message + ", ";
                }
            }
            response.TrimEnd(' ', ',');
        }
        else
        {
            response = "No Items Were Selected!";
        }
        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else if (act == "RemoveItemsFromProject")
    {
        string response;
        if (selected != null)
        {
            response = "Project Items Removed:";
            foreach (var item in selected)
            {
                if (ProjectItemRecordModel.DeleteProjectItem(projectId.ToString(), item))
                    response += item + " - deleted, ";
            }
            response.TrimEnd(' ', ',');
        }
        else
        {
            response = "No Items Were Selected!";
        }
        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    List<ItemRecordModel> items = ItemRecordModel.GetSensors(search_by, search, sort, sortdir);
    return View("Items", new AdminRecordsViewModel() { Records = items });
}
```

this was my old answer:
i solved your problem you need to change some stuff but you can accomplish a searchable listview with checkbox like so:

jsfiddle example:

---

basic:
[basic jsfiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/yakirmanor/SSgxM/)

nicer version:
[nicer version](http://jsfiddle.net/d8KNF/3/)

[jquery mobile listview with checkbox and icon or image](http://jsfiddle.net/yakirmanor/d8KNF/)